# SQL Server Cursor Locking Issue

Tags: sql-server

My application opens a cursor to perform updates/deletes on an indexed view.  While the cursor is opened, there are multiple page locks even though the query populating the cursor is doing a `select top 100`.

The query specifies `(UPDLOCK,READPAST)` query hints as multiple processes work from this queue. I would expect to see about 100 locks for this cursor, however I am seeing upwards to 67,000 locks for this cursor.

Also, I would expect that these locks would be on the ROW level, but they are on the page level, so maybe lock escalation?

Any ideas?

Cursor population SQL:

```
select top 100 
    col1, col2, col3 
from 
    indexedView with (updlock, readpast) 
order by 
    col3
```

Indexed view:

```
select 
    col1, col2, col3 
from 
    table 
where 
    col4 IS NULL
```

Thanks

Comment: The best idea would be to stop using a cursor for updates. Rewrite your update so it is set based.

Comment: Please share the code with us. What you have just described is like someone saying that their car is using a lot of gas - aren't cars better today? Row Escalation (in SQL Server) goes right to table escalation. Locks can initially be at row/page/extent level (and others)  but not escalation.